# ¿Cómo puedo comparar el input de una string en concatenación e iteración, sin listas?

Tags: python

soy nueva aprendiendo en "Python Programming MOOC 2022" y en mi ejercicio me pide que debo escribir un programa que le pida al usuario palabras, si el usuario escribe "end", el programa debe imprimir en una sola línea las palabras ingresadas sin la palabra "end"; adicionalmente, en ese mismo programa debo lograr que si el usuario ingresa dos veces la misma palabra, el programa igual finalice e imprima las palabras ingresadas incluyendo una sola vez la que se repitió.

```
words = ""

while True:
    
word = input("Please type in a word: ")
    
    if word == "end":
        break
    words += word + " "

print(words)
```

Esta es la primera parte, pero no encuentro la forma de lograr comparar el input del usuario con la palabra almacenada en la variable "words" alguna sugerencia o qué tema necesito estudiar o aprender para entender la solución del segundo planteamiento, agradecería mucho su aporte.

Comment: Supongo que no está permitido tampoco tuplas, diccionarios ni ningún otro tipo de secuencia más allá de las cadenas. Por ahora, voy a asumir que esto es cierto.

Comment: `if word in words:` te dice si la palabra ingresada está entre las previas.

Comment: Flor, ten en cuenta que la propuesta de candid moe no es magica. Si no que busca un pedazo de cadena en otra cadena. Por ejemplo, si tenes la cadena "hola mundo" y buscas "la mu", devolverá True. La idea de candid moe serviría correctamente solo si la "palabra" ingresada por el usuario no contiene espacios. Te digo esto por tu aprendizaje.

Comment: @CandidMoe No creo que sea buena idea decir que algo de Python hace lo que alguien busca sin aclarar un poquito lo que ocurre detras del telón, el OP podría llevarse una idea errada.

Comment: Probé con la propuesta de Candid Moe, muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y el aporte por cierto, y no funcionó porque digamos que la idea es que al ingresar las palabras "Once upon a time there was a girl" al momento de repetirse la "a" en la oración automáticamente corta con la instrucción a pesar de que no fueron consecutivos los ingresos de la letra "a".

Comment: Y en respuesta a @Dante S., también te agradezco mucho tu tiempo por responder, pero no, aún estoy en los primeros niveles de python, donde no he aprendido aún sobre tuplas o diccionarios, solo sobre variabales, operaciones aritméticas, condicionales y combinación de condicionales y loops simples que es donde viene incluido este ejercicio.

Answer (score 0):

Para almacenar palabras en una cadena, puedes hacerlo separando las palabras con algún caracter especial. Podemos usar el espacio, que es más conveniente.

Entonces, si tenemos las palabras *uno, dos y tres*, quedan almacenadas asi:

```
palabras = ' uno dos tres '
```

Al ingresar palabras tenemos que asegurarnos de que no incluyan el separador. Esto lo hacemos con `strip()`, que se encarga de eliminar todos los *white spaces* al comienzo y final de la cadena. Los *white spaces* incluyen espacios, tabuladores, cambios de línea, etc.

Teniendo la palabra ingresada por el usuario, le agregamos un separador a la cola y la buscamos en `palabras`. Así no hay manera de confundir una palabra corta con una larga. Por ejemplo, si ya tienes

```
palabras = 'luna sol estrella '
```

y el usuario ingresa

```
'ella'
```

el código va a buscar ' ella ', con un espacio por cada lado, lo que no calza con 'estrella'.

Finalmente, usamos `palabras.split()` para separar la cadena en sus palabras, producir una lista e imprimirla.

#### Demo

```
palabras = ' '
while True:
    nueva = input(">").strip()
    buscar = ' ' + nueva + ' '
    if nueva == 'end' or buscar in palabras:
        break

    palabras += nueva + ' '

print(palabras.split())
```

produce

```
>uno
>dos
>tres
>end
['uno', 'dos', 'tres']

Process finished with exit code 0
```